# Netty custom unique channel ID while or during handshake

Tags: netty, session-management, handshake

I have used the client/server chat example to implement my `SSL` requirements.
The main part of my requirement is `session management`.

I want to:

- Create `SSL` (`TLS`) "tunnels" from my clients to the server
- The `SSL tunnel` (`channel`) will only be opened and available, when specific requirements are fulfilled. Otherwise, the channel and hence the connection will be closed immediately.
- To check, if the requirements are fulfilled. The plan is, that the client sends an `ID` to the server. The `ID` will be for example assembled using the `client-PC-ID`, `Username`, `IP-Address`, `Timestamp`, etc. This `ID` can be used as the `channel ID` and as a `Client-Sesion-ID`, so that the server can locate/track/identify the user.

When creating an `SSL` connection, once the configuration is created, I am executing the `handshake()` method. The connection is then created and a random `Integer` is used as the `Channel-ID`. So, on the server side, I have the `ID`s of the clients and can send messages to them. But, I want to have my own unique `ID`s, which I can also use as `session ID`s. And most importantly, the clients will create these `ID`s and "login" using them. So I want to decide on the server side - using the `ID` created by the client - if the `TLS tunnel` (`channel`) will be opened (`logged-in`) or not (`no-access-to-log-in`). This needs the client to send the self-created unique `ID` during the `handshake`, doesn't it?

Once the client has sent a valid `ID`, the server should check, if the `SSL-Certificate` is valid, and so on. But this is the next step.

So, the question is, how can I use an `ID` sent by the clients? Or is this not possible? Or is it maybe not required? Or maybe it does not make any sense?

Any ideas on that?

Comment: To simplify the question, you want to send a custom data during SSL handshake phase and to let the server fail the handshake if the validation of the custom data fails.  Correct?  If so, why don't you just send the custom data (client ID in your case) *after* handshake is successful?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

After the handshake, the server uses an internal randomly generated ID as the "session id". Of course, I could associate the id with a channel in a Map, but that seems like a workaround.

On the other side, I will provide this functionality to many different clients. I don't want to tell them, that they have to send a special id after the handshake.

Comment: Actually, I could imagine havein something like this:
- The client makes a handshake and it send a certificate, which contains all the data needed to be able to open the connection and remain open, because the authentication was OK.
- From the certificate, the needed information can be extracted (but how?)